# Payment API Returns AuthenticationFailed Error

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am integrating payments to my app and using PHP-Payments-SDK from Intuit
When creating echeck debit by the following code.

```
public function echeck(Request $request){
    $this->refreshToken();  
    $record = QuickbookModel::first();
    $client = new PaymentClient([
        'access_token' => $record->accessToken,
        'environment' => "sandbox" //  or 'environment' => "production"
        ]);
        $array = [
            "bankAccount" => [
                "phone" => $request->phone,
                "routingNumber" => $request->routingNumber, 
                "name" => $request->name, 
                "accountType" => $request->accountType, 
                "accountNumber" => $request->accountNumber
            ],
            "description" => "Easyfi Testing", 
            "paymentMode" => "WEB", 
            "amount" => "5.55",
        ];

        $bank = ECheckOperations::buildFrom($array);
        $response = $client->debit($bank);

        if($response->failed()){
            $code = $response->getStatusCode();
            $errorMessage = $response->getBody();
            return json_encode(["status" => $code, "message" => $errorMessage]);
        }else{
            $responseCharge = $response->getBody();
            //Get the Id of the charge request
            $id = $responseCharge->id;
            //Get the Status of the charge request
            $status = $responseCharge->status;
            return json_encode(["status" => $status, "message" => $responseCharge, "data" => $id]);
        }

    }
```

I always getting following error even everything is up to mark including Access Token

```
{status: 401, message: "{"code":"AuthenticationFailed","type":"INPUT","message":null,"detail":null,"moreInfo":null}"}
```

Comment: Mmm, I'm no expert here (far from it) - but maybe there is a function you can call just like an 'info' one to check your token is ok. Maybe you just don't have enough permissions with your user/token?

Comment: @RichardHousham Can you please elaborate? Which type of info I have to fetch.

Comment: Try invoking the "createRequestForUserInfo" there is an example here.
https://github.com/intuit/PHP-Payments-SDK/blob/master/tests/OAuth2Test.php 
See what that brings back. Just want to check that at least the token is working with some standard 'run of the mill' request - before going full payment